# Specify different options for scp and ssh in .ssh_config file

Tags: ssh, scp, openssh

I am using `~/.ssh/config` file to set my ssh options.

I want to specify different settings for scp and ssh to the same host. Is it possible to do it?

I went through the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), but couldn't a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a second config file, `~/.ssh/scp_config`, and then use a shell alias for `scp` with the `-F` option to specify the config file:

```
alias scp="scp -F ~/.ssh/scp_config`
```

(This is an untested `zsh` alias; I don't know how different Bash alias' are, but the idea should be similar. Note also that this may still require you to use `scp -F <file>` in scripts).

Comment: This is an innovative way to solve the problem. Will select this answer if no one comes up with a better answer.